# Determine maximal path in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, directed-graph

I'm facing the problem of finding if all the maximal paths of a directed graph satisfy a certain condition: all the maximal paths (starting from a given "u" vertex) have to "contain" a vertex to whom is associated an even number. The definition my professor gave is "a path is maximal when you can't expand it anymore, i.e. when it's infinite or ends in a sink" which it may be a little confusing, at least for me, and I need a clarification for starting to think about the algorithm. For example, in the given graph, when u=0, how many maximal path are there? Which are them? 0-1-3 and 0-1-2 ? Could anyone, after that, also give me suggestions for the algorithm I need to write? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The concept of an infinite path is ambiguous. You would need to get instructions on what the exact output would be for such an infinite path (you don't want infinite output of course).

Comment: In your example the maximal paths are 1-3-0, 3-0-1-2 and 0-1-3.  Only 0-1-3 starts from 0.

Comment: @trincot unfortunately if the path is infinite is maximal and then, if that condition is verified, the algorithm would return true; if the maximal path exists but the condition is not verified it should return false. Anyway I'm not even sure on when a path is maximal, such as in the graph above

Comment: @btilly thank you so much! Please correct me if I'm wrong: 0-1-2 can't be maximal because I can add 3 like 0-1-3-0-1-2 and 0-1-3-0-1-2 can't be it also because I could do 0-1-3-0-1-3-0-1-2 and so on. It is correct?

Comment: @accr0 The vertices in a path have to be distinct.  So 0-1-2-0 is not a path and 0-1-2 is maximal.

Comment: @btilly sorry but I'm confused right now: is 0-1-2 a maximal path or no? And why vertices in a path have to be distinct? Why couldn't I say that 0->1->3->0->1->2 is not a path that starts in 0 and ends in 2 ? Thanks, sorry for bother you but I have the exam soon and I clearly need help

Comment: You should ask clarification to your teacher. Only they can clarify what they mean with an infinite path, and how that should be represented (with distinct nodes or not).

Comment: @trincot unfortunately I can't ask him, otherwise I wouldn't have asked here..but thanks anyway for the reply!

Comment: @accr0 It is all a question of definitions.  But as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory) says, a path usually is defined as a walk where all vertices are distinct.  So you can't complete any loops.

Comment: @btilly ok I've read the wiki and I can say that I need to find a walk and not a path - my professor called "simple path" the path and "path" a walk. Sorry about that. Now, do we agree that 0-1-3 is the only maximal walk and 0-1-2 is not a maximal walk because it can be extended as 0-1-3-0-1-2 ? Or am I wrong?